# Compute the greatest common divisor and least common multiple of two integers

Tags: python

I need to write a Python program in which the user enters two numbers and receives the LCM and HCF of those numbers. I tried it, and my LCM was correct, but my HCF was not, so could anyone assist me in locating the HCF? Thank you!

```
num1 = int(input('Enter your first number: '))
num2 = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
def compute_lcm(x, y):

   # choose the greater number
   if x > y:
       greater = x
   else:
       greater = y

   while(True):
       if((greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0)):
           lcm = greater
           break
       greater += 1

   return lcm
print("The L.C.M. is", compute_lcm(num1, num2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Euclidian algorithm if you want to find greatest common divisor or in your terms highest common factor (HCF): here is the link to the [article in FreeCodeCamp.org](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/euclidian-gcd-algorithm-greatest-common-divisor/)

Here is the code you can use for python for your case:

```py
"""  
finding HCF
"""

def hcfLoop(x : int, y : int) -> int:
    """  
    finding hinghest common factor using loop
    returns int
    """
    while (x % y) > 0:
        remainder = x % y
        x = y
        y = remainder
    
    return y

def hcfRecurs(x : int, y : int) -> int:
    """  
    find highest common factor using recursion
    """
    if y == 0 :
        return x
    else:
        return hcfRecurs(y, x % y)


x = 1220
y = 516
print(f"the HCF for {x} and {y} using loop: {hcfLoop(x,y)}")
print(f"the HCF for {x} and {y} using recursion: {hcfRecurs(x,y)}")
```

The answer:

```
the HCF for 1220 and 516 using loop: 4
the HCF for 1220 and 516 using recursion: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num1 = 36
num2 = 60
hcf = 1

for i in range(1, min(num1, num2)):
    if num1 % i == 0 and num2 % i == 0:
        hcf = i
print("Hcf of", num1, "and", num2, "is", hcf)
# HCF of 36 and 60 is 12
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is that
if you can get the LCM correct but can't get to the HCF
you can simply use the relation between LCM and HCF of two number ,i.e.
HCF*.LCM=a*b
where a and b are the numbers whose lcm you have calculated
Hope it helps